# Does MetaMascara have support for signing messages with a dialog box?

Tags: metamask

I'd like to add Web3 integration to an Electron app.  I found a Brave Browser fork of Electron that adds the MetaMask extension, but I'd prefer to stay in Electron if possible.  This brought me to MetaMascara, which looks like the tool I need.

Does MetaMascara have support for signing messages with a dialog box?

I've been poking around on https://github.com/MetaMask/mascara/tree/master/example and https://wallet.metamask.io/ but I can't quite get message signing to work right.